# Returns the address of a pointer with the help of Tcl API

Tags: c, tcl

I'm trying to return the address of a pointer with the help of Tcl API.
Below my simple function :

```
int simpleTest (Tcl_Interp* interp) {
    
    Context ctx;
    
    // init context
    Init(&ctx);
    // printf("%p\n", &ctx);
    
    Tcl_SetObjResult(interp, Tcl_ObjPrintf("%p", &ctx));

    return TCL_OK;
}
```

But I have this message :

> Unable to format "%p" with supplied arguments

I believe the [format](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/format.html) `%p` is not supported by the Tcl API.

How to do it ?

Comment: See you provid link [format](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/format.html)  at "DIFFERENCES FROM ANSI SPRINTF",  `2 %p and %n specifiers are not supported.`

Comment: @Tom Yes I know, that's what I wrote, there's a workaround ?

Comment: May be Yes, add one more  parameter, return pointer as parameter when you `Init` and `Tcl_SetObjResult` done. Or convert `the address of a pointer` to `long long` or `int`. Or print with `%x` or `%X`.

Comment: Try to print with `%x` or `%X` or `%d`. `the address of a pointer` is like `0x11FF3DA4` or `1345643`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you want to achieve, and how portable your implementation should be, you have at least two options:

a) Cast to an integer type (ideally: `uintptr_t`) and use the format specifier `%#llx`. (as suggested by @Tom)

```
Tcl_SetObjResult(interp, Tcl_ObjPrintf("%#llx", (uintptr_t)(void*)&ctx));
```

b) Use `sprintf` with `%p` to fill a buffer, and pass that to the Tcl tier (using the `%s` specifier):

```
char hexstr[24];
sprintf(hexstr,"%p", (void*)&ctx);
Tcl_SetObjResult(interp, Tcl_ObjPrintf("%s", hexstr));
```

I tend to have slight preference for b) because iff the objective is to present the result of `%p`, and given that `%p` is defined as "implementation-specific", you might not get the implementation-specific result at the Tcl level when using a).

### Update

As Donal suggests, using [`Tcl_NewStringObj`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclLib/StringObj.html):

```
char hexstr[24];
sprintf(hexstr,"%p", (void*)&ctx);
Tcl_SetObjResult(interp, Tcl_NewStringObj(hexstr, -1));
```

Comment: `Tcl_NewStringObj` (with -1 for length parameter) might be more appropriate in the second case. I'd recommend a 24 byte buffer instead of a 20 byte one; it's probably actually the same size (because of how alignments usually work), and yet it might be safer. It's not a waste of much memory!