# Getting the address of a pointer from Tcl_Obj

Tags: c, tcl

Related to my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77103156/returns-the-address-of-a-pointer-with-the-help-of-tcl-api).
I'm now trying to get this value in another function.
So far, I've mainly used `Tcl_Obj` to retrieve :

- char
- double
- list values
- etc...

But not an address of pointer. According to [Tcl API](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclLib/contents.html) ,such a function does not exist (I think...).
There aren't a plethora of examples (And most importantly, I don't know where/what to look for) on the net, I think this page [(Tcl Handles)](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Tcl+Handles) might help, but I'm not sure.
Can anyone give me some direction ?

**Edit** (Following the comment by @n. m. could be an AI) :

```
critcl::cproc initContext {Tcl_Interp* interp} ok {
    Context ctx;

    Init(&ctx);
    // printf("pointer %p\n", &ctx);

    char hexstr[24];
    sprintf(hexstr,"%p", (void*)&ctx);

    Tcl_SetObjResult(interp, Tcl_NewStringObj(hexstr, -1));

    return TCL_OK;
}

critcl::cproc useContext {Tcl_Interp* interp Tcl_Obj* ctxObj} ok {

    int len;
    char *strPointer;

    // Gets context pointer as a string
    strPointer = Tcl_GetStringFromObj(ctxObj, &len);

    // @Donal Fellows comment : 
    // "convert a pointer to an integer
    // (cast to intptr_t first) and an integer to a pointer"
    // I would like to reuse this context in this C function like this
    // showContext(&ctx);


    return TCL_OK;
}
# Tcl code
set ctx [initContext] ; # Gets context...
useContext $ctx ; # Using context
```

**Edit2** (Following the comment by @n. m. could be an AI. A minimal reproducible example) :

My C code that works :

```
void testContext() {
    Context ctx;

    if (Init(&ctx) != SUCCESS)
      return;

    showContext(&ctx);
}
```

Note : *I don't know if it matters, I'm using [critcl](https://andreaskupries.github.io/critcl/) (I think the philosophy is the same I hope so!)*.

Comment: "an address of pointer" is a strange thing to single out. Why would you need it, and not an address of an `int` for example?

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI, because my `C` level is elementary, and for me it's not the same thing.

Comment: Please show the Tcl calls that do work for you

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI, sorry I don't understand your request, side Tcl I have no problem , this a simple call : `set foo [myCfunction "0x7ff7bb374f98"]`

Comment: No I'm asking which TCL API functions you are using to get an iny for example.

Comment: [Tcl_GetStringFromObj](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclLib/StringObj.html)(myObj, &len)

Comment: This one returns a string representation of a value. It is good for printing for example. In what situation do you need to get an address of a pointer, and from what kind of object?

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI, In my first [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77103156/returns-the-address-of-a-pointer-with-the-help-of-tcl-api) I needed to initialize a context `Init(&ctx);`and return this context `ctx`. Now I need to reuse that context in a second `C` function by example : `showContext(&ctx); `and it's here that I'm stuck for retrieving this context from `Tcl` (aka `myObj`) via a `C` function.

Comment: You need to add your last comment to the question itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can just convert a pointer to an integer (cast to `intptr_t` first) and an integer to a pointer, and this will work. But it is desperately unsafe; there is no good way to validate those things directly! But there are things you can do.

The minimum level of validation is to pretend the pointer number with a name (maybe derived from the names of things it points to?) so that you don't mix them up completely by accident; you can easily check that when parsing values. A number of Tcl extensions do it this way.

A higher level of validation is to store a hash table in the Tcl interpreter (either as client data of commands or via `Tcl_SetAssocData`) and to use that to check that the value coming from the script is one that was given to it and that hasn't been invalidated yet (you usually invalidate when you free the thing it points to). Like that pointers can pass through the script, but only as opaque values. (My old code on that wiki page is doing a somewhat more advanced form of this, caching the mapping in the handle tokens themselves.) Tcl does something *very* like this for its native channel handles on Windows (other platforms use the FD instead).

(If you have such a table, it makes listing the currently known values an easy form of starter point for introspection.)

A slight extension to that is to use a counter (or RNG if you prefer) to generate the varying part of those handle names instead of the pointer part itself. Like that you make it impossible to map back without using your safety checks at all... but that usually isn't necessary. This is how synthetic channels (see `chan create`) create their handles. (TclOO *appears* to do this, but does something else; that has many more moving parts inside.)

The main thing to beware of in this is that you need to stop the mapping from working when you delete the value it points to (or otherwise make it unavailable). Tcl does not provide help with garbage collection (you can sort of trick it, and quite a bit of code does, but it is formally fragile and unsupported). Explicit deletion is the officially preferred approach.

Comment: I can't directly comment on what critcl does for pointer type mappings other than its standard set, but *if* it does anything then it *probably* does one of the options above. Read its docs to find out...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your method _convert a pointer to an integer (cast to intptr_t first) and an integer to a pointer_. If you have the time, can you show me a snippet of code?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need "an address of a pointer". You just need a pointer value.

You print a pointer to a string with what amounts to `sprintf(buffer, "%p", pointer)`, then convert it to a Tcl object.

The inverse operation would be `sscanf(buffer, "%p", &pointer)` Get a string trom the Tcl object and read it:

```
char* buffer = Tcl_GetString(obj);
void* ponter;
if (buffer == NULL || sscanf(buffer, "%p", &pointer) != 1)
{
    // report error
}

Context* pCtx = (Context*)pointer;
```

---

Below is a full tested working Tcl extension that uses the above method. Note how the context is static and not local to any command. You probably need to allocate it dynamically and manage its lifetime using Tcl object lifetime management, but this is out of the scope of this answer.

---

```
#include <tcl.h>

typedef struct Context
{
    int hour, minute;
} Context;

Context ctx = {7, 40 };

 static int 
 Hello_Cmd(ClientData cdata, Tcl_Interp *interp, int objc, Tcl_Obj *const objv[])
 {
    char hexstr[24];
    sprintf(hexstr,"%p", (void*)&ctx);

    Tcl_SetObjResult(interp, Tcl_NewStringObj(hexstr, -1));
     
    return TCL_OK;
 }

 static int 
 Bye_Cmd(ClientData cdata, Tcl_Interp *interp, int objc, Tcl_Obj *const objv[])
 {
     if (objc != 2)
     {
         Tcl_AppendResult(interp, "wrong # args", NULL);
         return TCL_ERROR;
     }
     char* buffer = Tcl_GetString(objv[1]);
     void* pointer = NULL;
     if (buffer == NULL || sscanf(buffer, "%p", &pointer) != 1)
     {
         Tcl_AppendResult(interp, "bad scan", NULL);
         return TCL_ERROR;
     }
     Context* pCtx = (Context*)pointer;

     Tcl_SetObjResult(interp, Tcl_ObjPrintf("The departure is at %d:%d", pCtx->hour, pCtx->minute));
     return TCL_OK;
 }

 /*
  * Hello_Init -- Called when Tcl loads your extension.
  */
 int DLLEXPORT
 Hello_Init(Tcl_Interp *interp)
 {
     if (Tcl_InitStubs(interp, TCL_VERSION, 0) == NULL) {
         return TCL_ERROR;
     }
     /* changed this to check for an error - GPS */
     if (Tcl_PkgProvide(interp, "Hello", "1.0") == TCL_ERROR) {
         return TCL_ERROR;
     }
     Tcl_CreateObjCommand(interp, "hello", Hello_Cmd, NULL, NULL);
     Tcl_CreateObjCommand(interp, "bye", Bye_Cmd, NULL, NULL);
     return TCL_OK;
 }
```

Comment: I tested your example and got the following error message :`zsh: segmentation fault  tclsh test.tcl`

Comment: Perhaps this error is related to another question...

Comment: I cannot debug your application without having the entirety of it. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: I edited my question with my C code that works.

Comment: Your `Context ctx;` is local to `initContext` and ceases to exist as soon as `initContext` returns. The pointers becomes invalid and any use of it triggers undefined behaviour.

Comment: If I understand, it is not possible to share my context `ctx` between 2 different function ?

Comment: You can share anything between different functions, you just need to do it the way C programs do. It is not recommended to learn the C ways from random SO answers though. Get a C book. Also see the updated answer.

Comment: _Get a C book_ , +1 That might not be a bad idea. In any case, thank you for taking the time to answer my questions.